# Jquery ошибка на canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, javascript

помоги разобраться. при выполнении кода в функции

```
function grayscale(src) {
    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
    var img_Obj = new Image();
    img_Obj.src = src;
    canv.width = img_Obj.width;
    canv.height = img_Obj.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img_Obj, 0, 0);

    var img_pxl = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

    for (var y = 0; y < img_pxl.height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < img_pxl.width; x++) {
            var i = (y * 4) * img_pxl.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (img_pxl.data[i] + img_pxl.data[i + 1] + img_pxl.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            img_pxl.data[i] = img_pxl.data[i + 1] = img_pxl.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(img_pxl, 0, 0, 0, 0, img_pxl.width, img_pxl.height);
    return canv.toDataURL();
}
```

появляется ошибка

```
Uncaught IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
```

ругается на строку

```
 var img_pxl = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
```

не подскажите в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы параметры высоты и ширины получаете до того, как картинка загрузилась. заверните ваш код после объявления `var img_Obj = new Image();` в событие load для этой картинки, а потом меняйте src.

Comment: да спасибо помогло!